# Can someone help me solve msm_media_info error -Werror,-Wsign-conversion?

Tags: android

Device Model #: pixel

Device Shipping Name: GOOGLE PIXEL

Device Codename: sailfish

Stock Android Version: 10

Android Version You Are Building: 13

ROM You Are Building: pixel experience 13 plus

ROM Github Organization: https://github.com/PixelExperience

Device Repo: https://github.com/SmalldemonLiu/device_google_sailfish

```
https://github.com/SmalldemonLiu/device_google_marlin
```

Kernel Repo: https://github.com/SmalldemonLiu/kernel_google_marlin

Vendor Repo: https://github.com/SmalldemonLiu/vendor_google_sailfish/tree/thirteen

Other Repos:

List Of Things You Have Tried To Do To Try And Resolve This Error:

```
To try the solution, I searched on Google and asked about Microsoft copliot and Google gemini. I also tried the methods they answered, but still couldn't solve it.

Modify the code configuration in msm_media_info.h and change the passed parameters to unsigned int. Because the error is still reported, I changed it back and used the export CFLAGS="-Wno-error,-Wno-sign-conversion" provided by Google gemini to ignore the problem.  , but still reported an error.



buidlog

https://hastebin.com/share/ragilafapi.yaml
```

Comment: Solved, just copy the hardware/qcom in the lineage20 directory to the hardware in the pixel experience13 directory and replace the original one.